# problems with map with Promise.All returns error before my promise done

Tags: javascript, api, rest, express

I hope you have a great day.

Ok so, I'm doing an API with **Express** in **Javascript**. So one function contains a Stored Procedure from **MySQl**.

When I running this function all execute correctly but returns error. **Later returns error still my console is running**, so i think i did something wrong.

My function is this. This data i need it for create a csv file

```
const getActivitiesForUser = async (user, index) => {
  try {
    let exeData = {};


    exeData.name = promedios[0][index].nombre;
    await sequelize.query(`call getActivitiesForUser(${user.dataValues.userId}, '${editionName}' )`)
    await sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM temp_AlumnoActivitiesSchedule')
      .then((result) => {

        let tempActividades = actividades[0];
        result[0].map((item) => {

          //Existe este item en actividades ? 
          for (let index = 0; index < tempActividades.length; index++) {
            // console.log( tempActividades[index].actividad );
            // console.log( item.actividad );
            if (item.actividad === tempActividades[index].actividad) {
              exeData[`${item.actividad}`] = item.calificacion;
              tempActividades = tempActividades.filter(itemRem => itemRem.actividad !== item.actividad)
              break;
            }
            else {
              exeData[`${item.actividad}`] = 0;
            }

          }
          worksheet2.push(exeData);
        })
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Well, I need get some activities for a lot users
I did it, here

```
   let promises = [];
studentGroup.map((user, index) => {
  promises.push(getActivitiesForUser(user, index));
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then((result) => {
    let set = new Set(worksheet2.map(JSON.stringify))
    let arrSinDuplicaciones = Array.from(set).map(JSON.parse);

    console.log(arrSinDuplicaciones);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })

const csv = json2csvParse2.parse(arrSinDuplicaciones);
```

maybe some variables doesnt exist in this code, I want to see if I wrong in the how i did the Promise.All.

Comment: What error is returned?

Comment: It is not return error, This code try set csv with arrSinDuplicaciones but it doesn't works because arrSinDuplicaciones doenst exists. I know this is problem with Promise.All.

Comment: `arrSinDuplicaciones` does not exist in the scope of the line where you are using it. It is declared inside the `.then` callback and you are trying to use it outside of that scope.

Comment: I'm not that great with async js but trying to learn, and I THINK you need an `async` in that map like [this](https://dev.to/jamesliudotcc/how-to-use-async-await-with-map-and-promise-all-1gb5)  What I'm learning so far is that anytime I see `await` and `then` in the same spot, it's probably not correct. Feel free to correct me on that though  =)

Comment: @Nikki9696 It technically runs, as `.then` does return a promise (which is why you can chain together `.then().then().catch()`), which can be `await`ed. I would generally not recommend the style, but that does technically run.